# With a STL map/set/multiset/multimap, How to find the first value greater than or equal to the search key?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Suppose I have a set of values, stored in a std::set:

{1, 2, 6, 8}

and I have a search key, say, 3. I want to put 3 into a function and get the first value greater than or equal to 3, in this case I would want to get 6.

The find() function provided in map/set/multimap/and set will, of course, return the end iterator for this case. Is there a similar function to find that would return 6 in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes: `upper_bound(X)` returns an iterator pointing to the first element greater than `X`.  There is also a `lower_bound(X)` function which returns an iterator pointing to the first element not less than `X`.  Thus, all of the elements in the half-open interval `[lower_bound(X), upper_bound(X))` will be equal to X.

Comment: Not "equal to X" but equivalent. For instance, in a case-insensitive set<string>, the lower_bound of "ABC" may be "abc". 
And for a std::set, "all elements in the half-open interval" will be at most 1 element.

Answer (score 3):

You want the [upper_bound](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/upper_bound.html) function.

```
map<int, int> mymap = { 1,2,6,8 };
map<int,int>::iterator i = mymap.upper_bound(3); // returns an iterator to the '6' element.
```

Answer (score 2):

[lower_bound](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/lower_bound).

Oops, I meant [lower_bound](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/set/lower_bound), the member function, not the algorithm.

If there's nothing in the set that's greater than or equal to your search item, it will return end().